# Квалификация и профессия в отрыве от учебного заведения

Tags: семантика

Можно ли назвать профессией род знаний и умений, не приобретаемых в учебном заведении, а полученных в результате самообучения, частного обучения под руководством мастера? Можно ли сказать о дилетанте-музыканте, поверхностно владеющем необходимыми умениями и навыками, что его профессия - музыкант? То же самое интересует и относительно квалификации: можно ли о ней говорить не в связи с учебным заведением, а просто как о совокупности знаний, умений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Можно ли назвать профессией род знаний и умений, не 
  приобретаемых в учебном заведении, а полученных в 
  результате самообучения, частного обучения под 
  руководством мастера?
```

Можно.

> Говоря о профессии, люди обычно подразумевают какой-либо род занятий
>   или вид трудовой деятельности, осуществление которой невозможно без
>   приобретения знаний, квалификаций **или практической подготовки.** При
>   этом овладеть профессией можно обучаясь в соответствующем заведении
>   или в результате обширного практического опыта.

https://businessman.ru/new-chem-otlichaetsya-specialnost-ot-professii-sut-ponyatij-ix-xarakteristika-i-otlichiya.html

Слово профессия нужно отличать от слова специальность. Разница в  объеме. Профессия – более широкий, общий термин, который может охватывать определенное количество специальностей. Например, доктор – это и педиатр, и эндокринолог, и терапевт, и многие другие. Главное, **чем отличается специальность от профессии**, – это то, что ***для овладения первой обязательно требуется обучение, а полученный документ действителен на ограниченной территории. Вторая же может быть приобретена в результате практических тренировок и упражнений (строители, продавцы, водители). Особенность некоторых профессий в том, что для их приобретения невозможно обойтись без уникальных личных качеств и талантов: это, например, певцы, актеры, музыканты, художники.***

```
  Можно ли сказать о дилетанте-музыканте, поверхностно 
  владеющем необходимыми умениями и навыками, что его 
  профессия - музыкант?
```

Об этой профессии мы уже сказали, что для неё необходимы уникальные личные данные и таланты. Если это музыкант, поверхностно владеющий необходимыми умениями и навыками, он не профессионал, он дилетант. То, что он избрал музыку средством зарабатывания денег, не говорит о том, что это его профессия, о нём можно сказать "*работает там-то и там-то*"

```
 То же самое интересует и относительно квалификации: 
 можно ли о ней говорить не в связи с учебным 
 заведением, а просто как о совокупности знаний, 
 умений?
```

Квалификация – это понятие очень широкое, его термин имеет два основных перевода. С английского языка термин переводится как «качество», что означает **степень проявляемых достоинств.** В более древнем переводе (с латинского) слово "квалификация" – это сочетание слов «какой» и «делать». Иначе говоря, **насколько хорошо то, что делается**.

В зависимости от области применения, термин означает **оценку степени качества или же предусмотренные уровни.**

Квалификация – это довольно обширное понятие. **Существуют различные ее типы, выделяемые в зависимости от сферы применения**: *в образовании это – уровень подготовки тех, кто закончил учебное заведение (среднее или высшее); в трудовых отношениях – уровень проявления профессиональных качеств, степень пригодности к определенным требованиям; в спорте – предварительные (отборочные) соревнования; в уголовном праве – оценка конкретного общественно-опасного действия.*

> Помимо разделения по сфере применения, различают квалификацию
>   работника и работы. Квалификация работника **Для работника квалификация
>   – это степень его обученности в профессиональном смысле**. Другими
>   словами, это уровень его подготовки, наличие опыта, теоретических и
>   практических навыков для выполнения определенного вида деятельности.
>   Чаще всего квалификация устанавливается в виде категории или разряда.
>   Работник имеет право пройти курсы повышения квалификации и получить
>   после этого более высокую категорию или разряд. От этого повысится и
>   его заработная плата. Но если сотрудник не сможет подтвердить
>   имеющуюся категорию, работодатель будет иметь право понизить ее и даже
>   разорвать трудовой договор. Процедура определения уровня подготовки
>   профессионала имеет свои особенности в каждой отдельной стране. Они
>   прописаны в трудовом законодательстве. :
>   https://www.syl.ru/article/191943/new_kvalifikatsiya---eto-professionalnaya-kvalifikatsiya

Доктором высокой квалификации без учебного заведения вряд ли кто станет, а вот токарем может стать практик, учившийся на заводе у мастера и потом самоучкой осваивал все сложные узлы. На категорию токарь может (вернее, мог раньше) сдать прямо на заводе - комиссия из мастеров определит степень его мастерства, а вот музыкант-самоучка вряд ли сможет сыграть перед высокой комиссией сложное музыкальное произведение, чтобы показать свою высокую квалификацию, которую подтвердит соответствующий документ. Документ о квалификации должен быть, а там будет и предыдущая квалификация, т.е. специализация, которая указывается в документе об образовании - дипломе. Так что опять-таки смотря какая профессия.

О квалификации **можно  говорить** не в связи с учебным 
 заведением, а просто как о совокупности знаний, 
 умений, **когда речь идёт о степени качества выполненной работы, а  не о специалисте.**

Что такое профессиональная квалификация?

> Работа требует той или иной квалификации, определяемой в зависимости
>   от ее предполагаемой сложности и необходимого качества выполнения.
>   Чаще всего существуют следующие ступени: начальное профессиональное
>   образование позволяет быть рабочим; среднее образование – техником;
>   высшее – специалистом. Среди рабочих специальностей существует 6
>   разрядов, которые прописаны в специальной сетке. Как правило,
>   профессиональные училища выпускают рабочих 3-4 разряда. Для педагогов
>   существует своя сетка. Так после окончания высшего учебного заведения
>   педагог вступает в должность специалистом и работает без категории.
>   Далее он может повысить ее до 2-й, 1-й, высшей. Последней
>   квалификационной ступенью в педагогике является категория
>   учитель-методист. У служащих своя сетка. Она состоит из 18-ти
>   разрядов. Не стоит забывать, что в реальных условиях труда
>   квалификация по сетке не всегда соответствует настоящему мастерству.
>   Помимо повышения квалификации, у работника должно присутствовать
>   чувство ответственности, профессионального долга, гражданская
>   зрелость.